# "People who" or "people that"

Tags: grammar, phrases, verbs, sentence, conjunctions

I am doing homework and I got confused about this phrase when I was writing. I am not a native English speaker.

> (...) and the only way to do this was taking control of everything and being authoritarian towards the people **who/that** could not do anything about it.

I would be grateful if you help me clarify which word should I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Who" refers to people; "that" may refer to either people or things.  Use "who" if doing so would help your reader identity the antecedent.  That's not a problem with your text.

"... the only way to do this was **by** taking control ...."